# Order by in C# in two levels of array

Tags: c#, group-by

I have a class that has two properties.

```
public class Result{ 
    public User User {get;set};
    public List<Game> Games {get; set;}
}
```

I have a foreach loop that fetches data from database for each member and gets each members bet in several games.

```
var results = new List<Result>();
foreach(var member in members){
  //Get games from database
  List<Game> games = gamesFromDatabase;

  results.Add(new Result{ User = member, Games =  games});
}
```

The results list will end up like this.

```
results[0].Member = { Id: 1, Name: David}:
results[0].Games = [{GameId: 80, Points:8}, {GameId: 81, Points: 3},...
results[1].Member = { Id: 2, Name: Mark}:
results[1].Games = [{GameId: 80, Points:7}, {GameId: 81, Points: 8},...
results[2].Member = { Id: 3, Name: Jake}:
results[2].Games = [{GameId: 80, Points:5}, {GameId: 81, Points: 10},...
```

I want an array that has all users but only one game in it so I can show that Mark has just 5 points in game with id = 80. The new list should look like this:

```
newResults[0].Member = { Id: 1, Name: David}
newResuts[0].Game = {GameId: 80, Points:8}
newResults[0].Member = { Id: 1, Name: Mark}
newResuts[0].Game = {GameId: 80, Points:7}
```

I will order them so the winner is the one with the highest points

Can I do this by using 'group by' statement in c#. Or is it another smart way to make the next array?

Is it possible to make a group by on the result array on User properti and the a group by on the games array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I understood from your question can be accomplished using this.

```
public class Result2 { 
    public User User {get;set};
    public Game Game {get; set;}
}

var gameId = 80; // Id of game by which you want to filter
var newResults = results.Select(r => new Result2 {
    User = r.User,
    Game = r.Games.OrderByDescending(g => g.Points).FirstOrDefault(g => g.GameId == gameId)
}.ToList();
```

Comment: In this case I need to iterate over all the games to get the new list. I hoped a group by on GameId should do it but that might not be possible. I did not mention that I also want to show which place the user are in each game. For example David is on first place when gameId = 80 but in the next game David is on place third place but acumelated position points from 81 and 82 together is  David on third place as well

Answer (score 0):

Why create a whole new set just to determine the winner?

Just order the results by the points of the gameId, and take the first result's member (or whole result if needed)

```
int gameId = 80;
User winner = results.OrderBy(r => 
                  r.Games.First(g => g.GameId == gameId).Points
              ).First().Member;//or stop here and take the ordered results
              //could also be a projection of entire result or user and points
```